# Cannot set property of innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have a small script which grabs a file and outputs in Javascript. Then after that output i want to edit the innerHTML.

But its saying it cannot set it. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

This is what i have:

```
function call_file(file,div_id){

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",file,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}




call_file('test.php','main'); //main = div_id to display content in 
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 'test';
```

My test.php has:

```
<div id="total"></div>
```

I'm wondering why it cannot set?

Comment: Is the div total inside main? If so, you've blatted it when you set the innerhtml for main.

Comment: @Sebas its in the question :P near top

Comment: @JeffWatkins when i set the innerHTML of main with "test.php" it should be adding the div "total" to main so it should exist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to set the innerhtml of total is happening before the state change event which happens in async. You'd have to ensure your Ajax call had completed before modifying the dom based on predicted added markup.

Comment: Onreadystatechange is an asynchronous callback, it will fire on a state change in your Ajax

Comment: So what should my function be instead?

Comment: You could create a function around your manipulation of test and call it in the state change callback at the bottom.

Comment: The two lines at the bottom of your listing, stick them in a function. Call that function as the last line of the onreadystatechange handler. in the status check block of course, not just arbitrarily.

Comment: I could but i use that function for many other things =/ so that would limit its use.

Comment: Try it just to see if it fixes your problem. Then you can come up with a more reusable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change second parameter of this line from 'main' to 'total', since that is the DIV, you expect the content in:

call_file('test.php','main'); //main = div_id to display content in

Comment: That wouldn't make sense... that would be add test.php into div id "total" when that div is in the script total.php. That is basically adding itself to itself.

Comment: @Sebas well i can assure ya its there cos the rest of my site is displaying in the div.